# Comment dit-on "What's wrong with you?" ?

Tags: traduction

Google Translate me dit que c'est "Qu'est-ce qui ne va pas ?" mais je crois que ça veut juste dire "What's wrong?".

Je souhaite dire "What's wrong with you?" et je ne veux pas être polie ou employer un registre soutenu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Une façon courante de poser cette question, le plus souvent d'une manière très inamicale :

> C'est quoi ton problème ?

ou les plus neutres :

> Qu'est-ce que t'as ?
> Qu'est-ce qui t'arrive ?
> Qu'est-ce qui te prend ? (Suite à un comportement surprenant)
> Quelle mouche te/vous pique ? (Registre soutenu ou décalé)

D'autres suggestions extraites des commentaires de @GabrielB et @Michael Harvey:

> Mais t'es pas bien ? (familier)
> Mais t'es malade (ou quoi) ? (familier)
> T'es tombé sur la tête ?
> T'as perdu la raison ? (soutenu)

> T’as craqué ton slip ou quoi ? (très familier, humoristique ou humiliant)

Comment: Suggestion: "qu'est-ce qui te prend ?" - quand le comportement de la personne est surprenant.

Comment: @Greg Je prends ! ;-)

Comment: J'aime aussi beaucoup le "Quelle mouche te pique ?"

Comment: @LaurentS. Je prends aussi, mais c'est très soutenu...

Comment: Pour “quelle mouche te pique” (ou plutôt “t'a piqué(e)”), on trouve cette expression dans les albums de Tintin, donc ce n'est pas si soutenu... Mais c'est, disons, pittoresque. Je proposerais aussi : “Mais t'es pas bien ?” “Mais t'es malade (ou quoi) ?” “C'est quoi ton problème ?” “T'es tombé sur la tête ?” Plus soutenu (mais également dans Tintin) : “T'as perdu la raison ?” // Pour “qu'est-ce qui te prend ?” il n'y a pas de -s à la fin du verbe, le sujet est “ce” (d'où conjugaison à la 3ème personne), le pronom “te” étant complément d'objet indirect (équivaut à : “qu'est-ce qui prend à toi”).

Comment: T’as craqué ton slip ou quoi ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey For a moment, I thought this was directed to me 

Comment: @GabrielB Oui, le *s* était une coquille due au fait que je venais d'écrire *je prends*.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing idiomatic that translates this English idiom in all circumstances. However it corresponds to a family of locutions which all have in common the same beginning (idiomatic). You complete this beginning with by a few appropriate words (dictated by the context).

- (*Someone staring at you and looking angry*)
  Qu'est-ce tu as à **me regarder comme ça** ?
  Qu'est-ce que vous avez à **me regarder comme ça** ?
- (*Someone starting a row*)
  Qu'est-ce que tu as à **te mettre en colère** ?
  Qu'est-ce que vous avez à **faire des histoires** ?
  Qu'est-ce que vous avez à **nous faire des histoires** ?
- (*Someone sneering*)
  Qu'est-ce que vous avez à **ricaner** ?
- (*Someone getting irritated against you*)
  Qu'est-ce que vous avez à **vous énerver** ?
- …

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context it can be something like :

> Qu'est ce qui va pas chez toi?

Answer (score 1):

As a non native speaker I would use [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/What%27s%20wrong%20with%20you%3F) for such idiomatic translations:

> Qu'est-ce qui ne va pas chez toi ?

rather than Google. Another alternative is [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/what%27s+wrong+with+you.html)

> "Qu'est-ce que t'as ?

[image]

**EDIT** Linguee and Deepl are strongly related and backed by the same data. Linguee (the company, created by a former Google employee) was recently renamed Deepl. While Deepl translations are generally well above other tools, they aren't the best solution to produce informal and rude sentences as asked here. (thanks to the native speaker @jlliagre for his comment.)

Comment: Linguee and Deepl are strongly related and backed by the same data. Linguee (the company, created by a former Google employee) was recently renamed Deepl. While Deepl translations are generally well above other tools, they aren't the best solution to produce informal and rude sentences as asked here. "Qu'est-ce que t'as ?" is not bad though.

Comment: DeepL is mostly best for translating huge chunk of written works (e.g. articles, books).

Answer (score 0):

On peut aussi dire (registre familier):

> Ça va pas ou quoi ?

Et une légère variation:

> Non mais ça va pas ou quoi ?